# Tabs title in the TabLayout does not scroll up when the viewpager is scrolled

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

Hi guys I have a problem setting up my tab layout, I have done it to the best of my ability & knowledge but I cant get it to work.
Here is the scenario:
[As you can see the tabs are stuck at the bottom just above the viewpager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npev0.png)

i have set up the tab layout inside the coordinator layout but when I try to scroll up the tab strips do not move, the view pager overlays and scrolls on top of the tabs. the tabs are stuck at the bottom, here is my code maybe ou guys can help me:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" app:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout" app:layout_width="match_parent" app:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar" app:id="@+id/mapAppbar" app:fitsSystemWindows="true" app:layout_width="match_parent" app:layout_height="UNKNOWN_DATA_0x1f401">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout app:id="@+id/main_collapsing" app:fitsSystemWindows="true" app:layout_width="match_parent" app:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_scrollFlags="3" app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp" app:contentScrim="#f15524">
        <fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" android:id="@+id/map" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="UNKNOWN_DATA_0x1f401" android:layout_scrollFlags="5" android:layout_collapseMode="2" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="UNKNOWN_DATA_0x7f010047" android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light" android:layout_collapseMode="1" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|center_vertical|fill_vertical|center|fill" android:id="@+id/tabLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="UNKNOWN_DATA_0x7f010047" android:layout_collapseMode="1" android:tabIndicatorColor="#233" android:tabMode="0" android:tabTextColor="#1b1b1b" android:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/viewPager" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right|center_vertical|fill_vertical|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center|fill|start|end" android:id="@+id/fab" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="16dp" android:fabSize="1" />
```

Comment: i couldn't understand your requirement, also your link to snapshot image does not show any tabs. Can you explain? Do you want to implement nestedScrollView feature??

Comment: Thanks, there are tabs at the bottom just right next to the google logo(Bottom right). Im trying to implement the collapsing toolbar layout but I cannot get he tabs to scroll together with the other contents, they are always left at the bottom and hidden behind the viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your class:

```
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```